# Cython class initialization in ray

Tags: python, class, cython, ray

I'm using Ray (https://github.com/ray-project/ray) and Cython 0.29 to parallelize some existing code, and I decided to define a cdef class with one of my Cython functions as its method to ease running the code for multiple Actors in paralell. The problem I've run into is that when I create an instance of my  class following the cython_simple.py ([example6)](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/master/doc/examples/cython/cython_main.py), I get a "Too many arguments to __init__ error".

I have a few questions, but the first is **how to correctly give my class instance its arguments when it gets decorated by ray.remote.**

I've been trying this method where Test is the imported class:

```
    import ray
    from cython_test.cython_test import Test
    ray.init()
    Test1 = ray.remote(Test)
    #Instatiate an actor
    args = (img, 10, 10)
    a1 = Test1.remote(*args)
```

But I  get back:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "test_ray_cython.py", line 25, in <module>
        a1 = Test1.remote(*args)
      File "/local/data/home/gmosby/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/actor.py", line 282, in remote
        return self._remote(args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
      File "/local/data/home/gmosby/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/actor.py", line 384, in _remote
        kwargs)
      File "/local/data/home/gmosby/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/signature.py", line 221, in extend_args
        .format(function_name))
    Exception: Too many arguments were passed to the function '__init__'
```

Additional Info: The Cython class here was initialized as `def __init__(self, img, nx, ny)`

Is it the case that if I want to use a Cython class with Ray it must not have any initialization arguments?

WORKAROUND found: It does appear decorating Cython classes with positional arguments in their __init__ methods fails, but I’ve decided to just move the setting of some class members to a separate function. See illustration of this issue and workaround here (https://github.com/astrophysaxist/cython_test)

Comment: How many arguments do you believe the constructor expects?

Comment: Here are some docs: https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/releases-0.7.3/example-cython.html

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with Ray and nothing to do with Cython. A simpler [mre] would be: `class Test: def __init__(self): pass` then `Test(1,2,3)` - you have a constructor that wants one argument and you're passing it more

Comment: @DavidW I think this may probably arise from an unspoken Ray rule. It seems it's not acceptable to have Cython classes with positional arguments in their `__init__`. See https://github.com/astrophysaxist/cython_test. Once I removed the extra arguments to `__init__` from my Cython function remote was able to create the class instance no problem.

Comment: In future it would be good to put this information in the question. The class you were using when you asked was a regular (rather than `cdef` class) and had a constructor that only took `self`. Your question __must__ demonstrate the problem you're reporting

Comment: Here's another illustration of this bug https://github.com/DerwenAI/rayCy_bug

FWIW, I author and teach some of the tutorials for Ray, and this issue was not obvious.

Answer (score 1):

WORKAROUND found: It does appear decorating Cython classes with positional arguments in their __init__ methods fails, but I’ve decided to just move the setting of some class members to a separate function. See illustration of this issue and workaround here (https://github.com/astrophysaxist/cython_test)